# How can I remove some opcodes from Java class file?

Tags: java, assembly, bytecode-manipulation

Here are some code lines:

```
//   43: invokevirtual 10   test/main:a (I)test/sub1;
//   46: pop
//   47: goto +4 -> 51
//   50: athrow
//   51: aload_2
```

This is the byte code of a sample Java class file.

I want to remove the opcodes of lines 47, 50... from java class file.

How can I do this using ASM?

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"?  What is the aim here?

Comment: I want 
//   43: invokevirtual 10   test/main:a (I)test/sub1;
//   46: pop
//   47: alod_2
after change java class file...

Comment: If I remove them using CCk(Class Construction Kit), then OK.
But if I remove them using ASM, then errors throws...

Comment: But **why** do you want/need to do this?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I want to do this for decompiling programmatically

Comment: @SkyDragon, most likely the reason you're getting errors is because simply removing the instructions means that the stack and locals now have invalid types. If you explain what you're actually trying to do, I might be able to help you come up with a better solution.